# How to make particular position of recyclerview item as highlighted by default in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

We are using a recyclerview, which has five rows. In each row we will be able to set imageview and textview. We want a particular position of recyclerview item (That is,Textview) should highlight by default.If we click some other position in recyclerview, that highlight should change from default position to selected position.If we again click on some other position, the highlight should change from previously clicked position to new one.Can someone please suggest us how to make this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post something that you have tried. That will help us.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Have a `int selectedPos = 0;` in the `RecyclerView` Adapter class, and inside `onBindViewHolder` method do the following:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {   
    viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(selectedPos == position);

}
```

in your `OnClick` event implement:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
     notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
     selectedPosition = getLayoutPosition();
     notifyItemChanged(selectedPos); 
}
```

this should give you idea to implement what you planning.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. We have tried code snippet as mentioned above. It works only for switching of recyclerview items. It doesn't work for particular recyclerview item as highlight by default.